# "I think therefore I am" parataxis?

Tags: coordinating-conjunctions

Is the sentence "I think therefore I am" a case of parataxis (joining sentences without a conjunction)?

Comment: Who so joined them? The Latin, French, and English versions I’ve seen all have a comma.

Comment: You can put a comma there but still no conjunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Wikipedia article contrasts parataxis and hypotaxis:

> Parataxis roughly translates to "arranging side by side", while hypotaxis translates to "arranging under". Parataxis omits subordinating conjunctions while hypotaxis utilizes them such as the terms "when", "although", and "after". Parataxis juxtaposes ideas and thoughts, while hypotaxis subordinates ideas to one another and can show both juxtaposition and transition. Because of this, hypotaxis can show relationships of cause and effect, chronology, and comparison.[8]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parataxis

With or without punctuation, “therefore,” like “so,” expresses a consequence, and is an adverbial subordinator that expresses a relationship, a consequence, rather than a parallel concept. Thus it’s not parataxis.

This conclusion depends on what you think the author meant. If you disagree, go to philosophy.se.

But because syntactic analysis changes doesn’t mean that the author’s meaning can be reinterpreted.